# How to create flavour app wih new plugins tag

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an android app with product flavors

## Flavor

```
productFlavors {
        googlePlay {
            versionCode 65
            versionName "6.1"
        }
        appGallery {
            versionCode 5
            versionName "1.0.3"
        }
}
```

And this gradle file uses google or huawei according to current selected flavor

## Old  working way

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
// Add the following line:
if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Google")) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services plugin
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
} else {
    apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
}
```

## New way [Not working]

The problem I have is when i tried to create a new project with Android Studio Electric , then i found this structure

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
//    if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Google")) {
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services plugin
        id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
//    } else {
//        id 'com.huawei.agconnect'
//    }
}
```

The problem is i couldn't uncomment the if else ? So how  to have old way with the new plugins tag ? as uncomment will give this error

## Error

> only id(String), alias(Provider), or alias(ProviderConvertible) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

## What I need

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
    if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Google")) {
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google Services plugin
        id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    } else {
        id 'com.huawei.agconnect'
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should uncomment this line too

id 'com.huawei.agconnect'

Comment: @EddieBrock i need to dynamically enable / disable them

Comment: @EddieBrock check What I need section in question edited

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the if/else block outside the plugins block ?
I tried and it doesn't give me error. It should just be checked if it works as expected.